# tensorflow - close session on object destruction

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, tensorflow, destructor

So I have a project with a classifier that tries to hide the tensorflow background from the user like this:

```
class CNN_Classifier:

    def __init__(self,
                 save_as='cnn_classifier.ckpt',
                 saved_model='cnn_classifier.ckpt'
                 ):

        # ...

        model_restorable = (
                saved_model is not None
                and os.path.exists(f'{saved_model}.index')
                )


        if self.debug:
            print('restore from file: {0}'.format('yes' if model_restorable else 'no'))

        self._session = tf.Session()

        saver = tf.train.Saver(self._tf_variables)
        with self._session.as_default():
            if model_restorable:
                saver.restore(self._session,saved_model)
            else:
                tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
                saver.save(self._session,save_as,write_meta_graph=False)

    def train(self,encoding='utf8',*examples):
        # makes use of self._session
        # periodically saves back to disk

    def predict(self,encoding='utf8',query):
        # makes use of self._session

    # ...
```

That way, we hope to avoid having to reload the classifier each time `train`, `predict`, etc. are called.

How do we *close* `self._session` when the user is done with the classifier / terminating script, though?

The 'obvious' way would be to simply push it into `__del__` and hope it will work out.

```
def __del__(self):
    if not self._session._closed:
        self._session.close()
```

And quite frankly, *I* don't see any other way to handle it.

If there's one thing I learned from googling about `__del__`, though, it's that it's always very strongly discouraged because it doesn't synergise with the garbage collector.

So is `__del__` the way to go or is there an alternative we are not yet aware of?

Comment: `Session.close()` ?

Comment: @user1735003 I think you missed the point ... the question is not about *how* to close a session, but *where* to close it.

Comment: Ok, that's clearer. You may have to rephrase your question though, because you ask 'How do we close `self._session`', and don't refer to `close()` in your code.

Comment: @user1735003 I had thought that would be clear from the question and the title, but ... done. Better?

Comment: Can you do [like TensorFlow Sessions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/client/session.py#L1309) and act as a context manager with `__enter__` and `__exit__` (so users would use `with` with your object)? There's already one layer of wrapping over Graphs. This ensures destruction during normal operation, although users can call those __ methods manually if they really need to (as you're considering with `Session` objects).

Answer (score 0):

Never, ever, *ever* use `__del__` in python - **ever**. It leads to excruciatingly painful bugs to track, yours truly has spent months on one of those.

@AllenLavoie is right:

```
class CNN_Classifier:

    # your code   

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self._session.close()
```

Then use your class:

```
with CNN_Classifier() as cnn:
    cnn.train()
```